# Do Android app early access users need to uninstall it and then re-install it when it is released to production

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have an Early Access Android app available on the Playstore. I sent the link of the app to a couple of my users and they directly downloaded it without enrolling in the beta resting programme. When I release my app to production will these users have to uninstall and re-install the app?

Answer (score 0):

that depends on signing key only. you can distribute your apk signed with release key with other than Google Play channels (e.g. sending mails) and all versions with same singing keys are installing one-on-another just fine (assuming updating, when higher `versionCode`)